# Kernel parameter SHMALL and SHMAX

Tags: rhel, database, shared-memory

I am using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11 (Tikanga) as OS and rdbms is 11gR2 software. I have created a database with memory_target=3 GB and 
physical RAM=7 GB. My DB service is getting slow when I do huge operations. I need to change the SHMALL and SHMAX parameters to improve the performance. Can you please suggest me how much values I should give?

Comment: What are your current values, RedHat sets that quite high by default.  Do your server have 7GB of memory or is that the limit placed on Oracle?  What is the page size on that machine (4k, 8k)?

Comment: hi,yes server is having 7 GB RAM.and page size is kernel.shmmni = 4096

Comment: # Controls the maximum number of shared memory segments, in pages
kernel.shmall = 4294967296
fs.suid_dumpable = 1
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.file-max = 6815744
kernel.shmmni = 4096
# semaphores: semmsl, semmns, semopm, semmni
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
net.core.rmem_default=262144
net.core.rmem_max=4194304
net.core.wmem_default=262144
net.core.wmem_max=1048586

Comment: $free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          6987       6942         45          0         11       3620
-/+ buffers/cache:       3310       3677
Swap:        15359       2922      12436

Comment: If you have kernel.shmall = 4294967296 (and SHMMAX is not below it) this is already way above 7GBs (4294967296*4096 > 7*1024^3).  You will need to optimise your queries, kernel tweaking will not give you more shared memory.

Comment: can we say due to this server is getting slow?

Answer (score 3):

### SHMAX

For 64-bit servers the optimal value you can use, is Half the RAM

While for 32-bit servers it is 3 gigabytes

### SHMALL

You should make SHMALL smaller than free RAM to avoid paging.

## SHMAX

From what we have on [RedHat Documentations on Setting SHMAX](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/chap-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Shared_Memory.html#sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Shared_Memory-Setting_SHMMAX_Parameter_):

> This parameter defines the maximum size in bytes of a single shared
>   memory segment that a Linux process can allocate in its virtual
>   address space. For example, if you use the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3
>   smp kernel on a 32 bit platform (x86), then the virtual address space
>   for a user process is 3 GB. If you use the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 3
>   hugemem kernel on a 32 bit platform (x86), then the virtual address
>   space for a user process is almost 4GB. Hence, setting SHMMAX to 4GB -
>   1 byte (4294967295 bytes) on a smp kernel on a 32 bit architecture
>   will not increase the maximum size of a shared memory segment to 4 GB
>   -1. Even setting SHMMAX to 4 GB - 1 byte using the hugemem kernel on a 32 bit architecture will not enable a process to get such a large
>   shared memory segment. In fact, the upper limit for a shared memory
>   segment for an Oracle 10g R1 SGA using the hugemem kernel is roughly
>   3.42 GB (~3.67 billion bytes) since virtual address space is also needed for other things like shared libraries. This means if you have
>   three 2 GB shared memory segments on a 32 bit system, no process can
>   attach to more than one shared memory segment at a time. Also note if
>   you set SHMMAX to 4294967296 bytes (4*1024*1024*1024=4GB) on a 32 bit
>   system, then SHMMAX will essentially bet set to 0 bytes since it wraps
>   around the 4GB value. This means that SHMMAX should not exceed
>   4294967295 on a 32 bit system. On x86-64 platforms, SHMMAX can be much
>   larger than 4GB since the virtual address space is not limited by 32
>   bits. Since the SGA is comprised of shared memory, SHMMAX can
>   potentially limit the size of the SGA. SHMMAX should be slightly
>   larger than the SGA size. If SHMMAX is too small, you can get error
>   messages similar to this one:
>
> ORA-27123: unable to attach to shared memory segment

## SHMALL

From what we have on [RedHat Documentation on Setting SHMALL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Setting_Shared_Memory-Setting_SHMALL_Parameter.html):

> This parameter sets the total amount of shared memory pages that can be
>   used system wide. Hence, SHMALL should always be at least
>   ceil(shmmax/PAGE_SIZE).
>
> The default size for SHMALL in Red Hat
>   Enterprise Linux 2.1, 3, 4 and 5 is 2097152 which is also Oracle's
>   recommended minimum setting for 9i and 10g on x86 and x86-64
>   platforms. In most cases this setting should be sufficient since it
>   means that the total amount of shared memory available on the system
>   is 2097152*4096 bytes (shmall*PAGE_SIZE) which is 8 GB. PAGE_SIZE is
>   usually 4096 bytes unless you use Chapter 14, Large Memory
>   Optimization, Big Pages, and Huge Pages which supports the
>   configuration of larger memory pages.
>
> If you are not sure what the
>   default PAGE_SIZE is on your Linux system, you can run the following
>   command:
>
> $ getconf PAGE_SIZE

Comment: we are using linux 5.11, if default size of shmall is 8 GB recommend by oracle then my server is having only 7 GB physical memory.How you suggest for this, do i need to reduce the size of shmall

Comment: i have given 3 GB MEMORY_MAX_SIZE to Database and i can put shmmax= 3.4 GB is it enough? how you suggest for this

Comment: I recommend you improve your physical memory first, and then change the values. BTW, it depends on what your DB is about, is it only yours and for test, or is it holding important data? The choice is yours, consider what your work is, and what you need. But I think you need to improve your physical memory, at least, that's what I would do if I were in your shoes.

Comment: but we have blade server on that we built the several virtual machines

Comment: and shmmax>= SGA as mentioned in docs but my question is shmmax>=SGA or shmmax>= memory_target or memory_max_size

Comment: for instance:- if we have 7 GB  RAM then can we give shmall greater than  RAM if we give what will be the issue and how much percentage of  RAM we have to give for shmall